# Pyqt5 List QtPushbutton add border-image

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qpushbutton, border-image

I'm using Python 3 ( Pycharm ) with Pyqt5 (Windows 10)

I need to use a list of QPushbutton. 
I managed to change the color of button, it's ok. 
Nevertheless, I couldn't change the image of border-image (same QT), into my function to add button (Add_Buttons_KA_IU) 
The structure of my repertory :

My_Project :

```
|-> Vision_Room.py

|-> Ressource -> LightOff.png
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QWidget,QLabel,QLineEdit,QPushButton,QApplication,QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindows(QMainWindow):
    buttons_KA, keydata_KA = {}, {}
    Positions_Button_KA = [(330, 70, 10, 20),(270, 110, 10, 20),(300, 110, 10, 20),(360, 110, 10, 20),(330, 150, 10, 20),
                           (180, 190, 10, 20),(240, 190, 10, 20),(300, 190, 10, 20),(360, 190, 10, 20),(210, 230, 10, 20),
                           (270, 230, 10, 20),(330, 230, 10, 20),(180, 270, 10, 20),(240, 270, 10, 20),(270, 270, 10, 20),
                           (300, 270, 10, 20),(360, 270, 10, 20),(210, 310, 10, 20),(330, 310, 10, 20),(180, 350, 10, 20),
                           (240, 350, 10, 20),(300, 350, 10, 20),(360, 350, 10, 20),(210, 390, 10, 20),(270, 390, 10, 20),
                           (330, 390, 10, 20),(180, 430, 10, 20),(240, 430, 10, 20),(300, 430, 10, 20),(360, 430, 10, 20)]

    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_MainWindows,self).__init__()
        #self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.resize(1280,960)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.setWindowTitle("Vision Room")
        #self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.Add_Buttons_KA_IU()

    def Add_Buttons_KA_IU(self):
        Name_Button = "Button_KA"
        for i in range(0, 30):

            Full_Name_Button = Name_Button + str(i)
            print(Full_Name_Button)

            b = self.buttons_KA[i] = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)

            b.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.Positions_Button_KA[i][0],self.Positions_Button_KA[i][1],self.Positions_Button_KA[i][2],
                                       self.Positions_Button_KA[i][3]))


            #str_Style_Sheet = "#" + Full_Name_Button + "\n" "{\n""background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);\n" "}"
            str_Style_Sheet = "#" + Full_Name_Button + "\n" "{\n""border-image: url(:/Ressource/LightOff.png);\n" "}"
            print(str_Style_Sheet)
            b.setObjectName(Full_Name_Button)

            b.setStyleSheet(str_Style_Sheet)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Ui_MainWindows()
    MainWindow.show()

    rc = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(rc)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you are going to add QSS to each button it is not necessary to use objectName, on the other hand the problem is caused because you do not understand what the ":" means, the ":" indicates that you are using a qresource (.qrc) that is a file that allows to store files universally in Qt, and that is a virtual path, you should not use those ":" because you are not using it. On the other hand it is always better to have the fullpath of the files to avoid problems, but it must also be easy to manage, so the solution is to obtain the path of the .py and concatenate it with the relative path of the resource with respect to the .py, so you can move your project and even then it will work.

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

positions_button_KA = [(330, 70, 10, 20),(270, 110, 10, 20),(300, 110, 10, 20),(360, 110, 10, 20),(330, 150, 10, 20),
                       (180, 190, 10, 20),(240, 190, 10, 20),(300, 190, 10, 20),(360, 190, 10, 20),(210, 230, 10, 20),
                       (270, 230, 10, 20),(330, 230, 10, 20),(180, 270, 10, 20),(240, 270, 10, 20),(270, 270, 10, 20),
                       (300, 270, 10, 20),(360, 270, 10, 20),(210, 310, 10, 20),(330, 310, 10, 20),(180, 350, 10, 20),
                       (240, 350, 10, 20),(300, 350, 10, 20),(360, 350, 10, 20),(210, 390, 10, 20),(270, 390, 10, 20),
                       (330, 390, 10, 20),(180, 430, 10, 20),(240, 430, 10, 20),(300, 430, 10, 20),(360, 430, 10, 20)]


class Ui_MainWindows(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_MainWindows,self).__init__()
        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.setWindowTitle("Vision Room")

        self.buttons_KA = {}

        self.add_buttons_KA_IU()
        self.resize(1280, 960)


    def add_buttons_KA_IU(self):
        name_group = "button_KA"
        for i, geom in enumerate(positions_button_KA):
            b = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget)
            b.setGeometry(*geom)
            path_image = os.path.join(dir_path, "Ressource/LightOff.png").replace("\\", "/")
            qss = 'border-image: url({})'.format(path_image)
            b.setStyleSheet(qss)

            self.buttons_KA[i] = b

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Ui_MainWindows()
    MainWindow.show()

    rc = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(rc)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Linux:

[image]

Windows:

[image]

Comment: Hello eyllanesc , 

I understand more. 
I tried your code. 
Nevertheless, I have the same result : QPushbutton empty. 
You can trie if you take a small picture.

Comment: @JérômePannetier Share the image you want to use to check if the problem is caused by your image.

Comment: @JérômePannetier I have tried with the image that you show and my code works correctly, are you using my code without modifying it, first try it without modifying, on the other hand I have uploaded my test project so you can test it: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/53032423

Comment: you are into Linux or Windows ? 
I'm using Windows

Comment: I'm working into Windows 10 . I copied your code and I have always the same problem . 
I'll tried tomorrow into Linux

Comment: @JérômePannetier I fixed it, it seems that os.path uses the native separator, for example in windows it uses "\" but Qt expects "/", try again my solution.

Comment: Good new, it's working on my other computer (Linux). 
Thank you

Comment: @JérômePannetier As I already pointed out, I already corrected it for Windows, Linux and Mac OS. If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that's the best way to thank